# multiple plots and save them as an increment

Tags: python, plot

Now that its working like this way so I need to save them automatically in .eps format as an increment like 1.eps, 2.eps. Another thing, is there a way I can put the output of y like [1 1 1 1 1 1] on top of the each plot? I am quite new to python and thats why I am still trying to learn the things. The 3phases.txt file consists of 3 lines

```
1   1   1, 
1   -1  1, 
-1  -1  -1
```

The code again:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

D=13.0
n = range(1,7)
x = np.linspace(-0.3-D/2, 0.3+D/2, 3000)

q = np.array([0, 4.38,  12.61,  3.63,  0,  6.39])
f = open('3phases.txt','r')

for line in f.readlines():  
    line = line.split()
    line.insert(0, '1')
    line.insert(3, '1')
    line.insert(4, '1')

    t=map(float,line)

    y = np.array(t*q)
    d=sum(l*np.cos(2*np.pi*j*x/D) for j,l in zip(n,y)) 

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, d, 'ro')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to have a separate plot for each line of the input file? 
Then you can do along these lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('3phases.txt', 'r') as f:
   for j, line in enumerate(f):
      print line
      x = np.array([int(l) for l in line.split()])
      fig, ax = plt.subplots()

      ax.plot(x, x**2, 'ro')
      plt.savefig(str(j)+'.eps')
```

Alternatively, you might want to avoid creating new figures in a loop (especially if you've lots of them), create it once and reuse: then you'll need to clear it after saving, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/matplotlib-clearing-a-plot-when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close).

As a rule of thumb, I'd recommend avoiding the blanket imports from pylab, `from pylab import *`, unless you're in an interactive mode.

Comment: Hi, thnx for your answer. it was helpful. I reedited the question as I still need some guideline.

Comment: thnx, now I mamaged them to save also eps with file increment.