# memory leak in matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, memory-leaks, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

Running the following code will result in memory usage rapidly creeping up.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as p
mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100000)
for i in range(100):
    n, bins, patches = p.hist(x, 5000)
```

However, when substituting the call to pylab with a direct call to the numpy histogram method then memory usage is constant (it also runs significantly faster).

```
import numpy as np
mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100000)
for i in range(100):
    n, bins = np.histogram(x, 5000)
```

I was under the impression that pylab is using the numpy histogram function. There must be a bug somewhere...

Comment: You have to clear your figure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/matplotlib-clearing-a-plot-when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close if you really want to draw histograms in a loop. Plus do garbage collect if you use 2.x Python. But I guess drawing histogram wasn't your intention

Comment: Thanks! I did try gc.colletc() without success but adding a clf() inside the loop does the trick! (And you are right I didn't want to draw the histograms - I just wanted to use the functionality)

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib generates a diagram. NumPy does not. Add `p.show()` to your first code to see where the work goes.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as p
mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100000)
n, bins, patches = p.hist(x, 5000)
p.show()
```

You may want to try with a smaller number for `np.random.randn(100000)` first to see something quickly.

**EDIT**

Does not really make sense to create the same plot 100 times.