# Why does plt.savefig() performance decrease when calling in a loop?

Tags: python, image, performance, matplotlib, plot

I wrote the following code to test the performance of matplotlib's `savefig()`function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import time

for i in xrange(10):

    init = time.time()
    x = rand(100)
    y = rand(100)
    t_init=time.time()-init

    init = time.time()
    ax = plt.axes()
    t_axes=time.time()-init

    init = time.time()
    num, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x,y)
    t_hist = time.time()-init

    init = time.time()
    ax.imshow(num, extent=[-.5,.5,-.5,.5], interpolation="bicubic")
    t_imshow = time.time()-init

    init = time.time()
    t = ax.text(i*.1,.1, "Value ="+str(i))
    plt.savefig("test/"+str(i)+".png")
    t.remove()
    t_savefig = time.time()-init

    print t_init, t_axes, t_hist, t_imshow, t_savefig
```

Unexpectedly, the performance of `savefig()` decreases with every iteration, as shown in the last column of the following table:

```
t_inint           t_axes            t_hist            t_imshow         t_savefig
4.10079956055e-05 0.114418029785    0.000813007354736 0.00125503540039 0.668319940567
2.28881835938e-05 0.000143051147461 0.00158405303955  0.00119304656982 0.297608137131
1.90734863281e-05 0.000148057937622 0.000726938247681 0.0012149810791  0.356621026993
2.31266021729e-05 0.0001380443573   0.000706911087036 0.0011830329895  0.37288403511
2.28881835938e-05 0.000149011611938 0.000706195831299 0.00119686126709 0.416905879974
2.00271606445e-05 0.000148057937622 0.000704050064087 0.00118589401245 0.505565881729
2.19345092773e-05 0.000140905380249 0.000710010528564 0.00121307373047 0.494667053223
2.09808349609e-05 0.000147819519043 0.000703096389771 0.00119400024414 0.5519759655
2.09808349609e-05 0.000139951705933 0.000716209411621 0.0011990070343  0.624140977859
3.2901763916e-05  0.000142097473145 0.000709056854248 0.00120401382446 0.634006023407
```

What causes `savefig()` to slow down? How can I avoid this behavior? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to clear your axis between plots, adding `plt.cla()` will do the trick, there is a great [stackoverflow post about clearing figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/matplotlib-clearing-a-plot-when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close) that is worth a read.

Answer (score 3):

If you do plt.clf() between iterations, then the timing doesn't really increase.
My guess is that before you were overplotting on top of previous axes (accumulating them), which lead to longer savefig.