# Close pyplot figure using the keyboard on Mac OS X

Tags: python, matplotlib, osx-mavericks

Is there a way to close a pyplot figure in OS X using the keyboard (as far as I can see you can only close it by clicking the window close button)?

I tried many key combinations like command-Q, command-W, and similar, but none of them appear to work on my system.

I also tried this code posted [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/830/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))

def quit_figure(event):
    if event.key == 'q':
        plt.close(event.canvas.figure)

cid = plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', quit_figure)

plt.show()
```

However, the above doesn't work on OS X either. I tried adding print statements to quit_figure, but it seems like it's never called.

I'm trying this on the latest public OS X, matplotlib version 1.1.1, and the standard Python that comes with OS X (2.7.3). Any ideas on how to fix this? It's very annoying to have to reach for the mouse every time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in the default OS X backend used by pyplot. Adding the following two lines at the top of the file switches to a different backend that works for me, if this helps anyone else.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
```

Answer (score 13):

I got around this by replacing

```
plt.show()
```

with

```
plt.show(block=False)
input("Hit Enter To Close")
plt.close()
```

A hack at its best, but I hope that helps someone

Answer (score 0):

use **interactive mode**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Enable interactive mode:
plt.ion()

# Make your plot: No need to call plt.show() in interactive mode
plt.plot(range(10))

# Close the active plot:
plt.close()
# Plots can also be closed via plt.close('all') to close all open plots or
# plt.close(figure_name) for named figures.
```

Checkout the "What is interactive mode?" section in this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html)

Interactive mode can be turned off at any point with `plt.ioff()`

Answer (score -2):

When you have focus in the matplotlib window, the official keyboard shortcut is ctrl-W by this:

http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/users/navigation_toolbar.html

As this is a very un-Mac way to do things, it is actually cmd-W. Not so easy to guess, is it?

If you are using an interactive shell, you can also close the window programmatically. See:

[When to use cla(), clf() or close() for clearing a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/matplotlib-clearing-a-plot-when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close)

So, if you use pylab or equivalent (everything in the same namespace), it is just `close(fig)`. If you are loading the libraries manually, you need to take `close` from the right namespace, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([0,1,2],[0,1,0],'r')
fig.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

The only catch here is that there is no such thing as `fig.close` even though one would expect. On the other hand, you can use `plt.close('all')` to regain your desktop.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I already tried those... none work for me (neither cmd-W nor ctrl-W)

Comment: @edit: yeah I know about those, but those don't help relieve the annoyance. Basically I want it to popup a graph, I'll stare at it for a while and then I need a key combo that will just close it without having to use the mouse. I can't use close(fig) if I don't have a way to listen for key events (as mentioned in the question I tried adding a event handler)

Comment: I am afraid your problem is that the focus is not in the plot window. Do the key shortcuts work, if you move the focus? If so, then cmd-Tab + cmd-W...

Comment: focus is definitely in the window; for example if I hit tab it cycles over the buttons in the window on the bottom.

Comment: It seems like a bug to me, because the snippet I posted is supposed to work, but it doesn't

Comment: I agree, because all these tricks seem to work for me on a mac (IPython shell with macports python.) The standard OS X python seems to create more problems than solve, at least in scientific use.