# Matplotlib: Hang up on conditional plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code hangs,

```
while np.any((np.log10((O3 / HB)) < 0.61 / (np.log10(N2 / HA) - 0.05) + 1.3).any()):
    plt.plot(np.array(np.log10(N2 / HA)), np.array(np.log10(O3 / HB)), '.g')
plt.plot(np.array(np.log10(N2 / HA)), np.array(np.log10(O3 / HB)), '.r')
```

The plot works without the "while" condition. In the above form it hangs.
Do I need a "break"?

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to plot values from an array that meet a criteria? I think this is generally done using something like `plt.plot(xdat[bool_array], ydat[bool_array], ...)`. Where you define `bool_array` as something like `bool_array = (ydat > y_thresh) & (xdat < x_thresh)` or something. You don't need a `while` statement to do this.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're just trying to plot one point, you probably want to use `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: yes, the condition is

Comment: yes, the condition is: np.any((np.log10((O3 / HB)) < 0.61 / (np.log10(N2 / HA) - 0.05) + 1.3).any()). Depending on meeting the condition, the plot (several 100 point) is either red or otherwise green.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. A good place to start would be to provide a minimal example of how `N2`, `HA`, `HB` and `O3` defined? We don't want your entire code. I also suspect that this code-block is inside another loop. Am I correct?

Comment: Also, regarding your question 'Do I need a "break"?' The answer is: maybe, but if you're going to put `break` at the end of your `while` block, you should use `if` instead (without a `break`). It does exactly the same thing, and is much better code-style.

Comment: O3 = np.array(new_OIII)
HB = np.array(new_Hbeta)
N2 = np.array(new_NII)
HA = np.array(new_Halpha)
O1 = np.array(new_OI)
S2 = np.array(new_SII)
HE2 = np.array(new_HEII)
These are the definitions. The code block is not inside a loop.

Comment: This is not helpful because I don't know what `new_OIII`, `new_Hbeta`, `new_NII`, `new_Halpha`,  `new_OI`, `new_SII` or `new_HEII` are. Again, take a look at the [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page for guidance on asking a good question.

Answer (score 0):

The code probably freezes because you are making a new plot object every time the loop iterates, eventually you'll run out of memory. The program usually spits out a warning after 20 or so plots made.

You can clear the axis each time as an alternative, or

[When to use cla(), clf() or close() for clearing a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/matplotlib-clearing-a-plot-when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close)

or you could use the `.set_xdata`, `set_ydata` commands to simply update the data. Or you could reuse the same axes if you want to overlay the data.

Answer (score 0):

### Discussion of Issue

The code freezes because you are using a `while` loop with a condition whose variables do not change within the loop. Therefore, if the condition evaluates to `True` the first time through the loop, it will evaluate to `True` indefinitely, (i.e. the code 'hangs'). Typically (unless you *want* the loop to run forever) one or more variables within a `while` loop will change within the loop. A very simple example is,

```
while index < 10:
    plt.plot(x_data[index], y_data[index])
    index += 1  # Here the index changes.
```

*Note:* For these purposes it is more common to use `for index in range(10):` or better yet `for xd, yd in zip(x_data, y_data): plt.plot(xd, yd)` rather than a `while` loop because then you don't need to have the `index += 1` line, and it is clearer at the beginning of the loop what is going on. I merely provided this as a clear example use of `while`.

Even if the conditional variables do change within the loop (i.e. if you're only providing a snippet of your `while` loop), it is possible that the conditional statement always evaluates to `True`. In this case, again, you will never exit the `while` loop and your code will 'hang'.

### Potential Solutions

There are several ways you could fix your problem depending on what you are trying to do:

1. If you just want to plot your data once, use `if` instead of `while`.
2. If you are only showing us a snippet of your loop and the variables in the conditional statement *do* change within the loop, I would recommend:

   A) starting by placing a `print(np.any((np.log10((O3 / HB)) < 0.61 / (np.log10(N2 / HA) - 0.05) + 1.3).any()))` at the top of your loop and run your code. I presume this will dump `True` to your console.

   B) You could then start to break this statement apart using more print statements such as `print('N2: %f' % N2)` to understand why your statement is never evaluating to `False` and therefore you are never exiting the loop.