# How to clear all dynamically plotted points on pyplot scatter graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am using Pyplot in Python.

I know that you can pick and choose which points in particular you wish to remove, but this also affects the axis which I want to keep constant. Also, the points I generate are dynamically created (meaning I do not know what they are until they are actually made). Is there a method in a while I can basically wipe all the points of the graph but keep the same axis? I'd rather not have Python close the old window and create a new one.

Thanks for you help! Let me know what I need to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you retrieve the maximum and minimum limits through something like:

```
ymax,ymin = axes.get_ylim()
```

And then use that to re-initiate your new plot?

Comment: Yes. I guess my confusion is actually re-initiating the new plot without closing and opening a new window each time.

Comment: You can use `plt.clf()` to clear the current figure without closing the window

Comment: The clf() worked really well. However I just need to restate what the the axis are, although this doesn't slow things down too much. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the [clear](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=clear#matplotlib.axes.Axes.clear) method on the axis or the [remove](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection.remove) method on the PathCollection that is returned by the scatterplot. See also the discussion of the details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/matplotlib-clearing-a-plot-when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close) answer. This is an example that keeps the axes and clears the points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
paths = ax.scatter([3,2,1,4], [2,3,4,0])
paths.remove() # to just remove the scatter plot and keep the limits
```

Or:

```
ax.clear() # to clear the whole axes
```

edit: added example on how to just remove the points

Comment: ax.clear() appears to also be clearing the limits.. unfortunately