# how to Clear graph tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, graph, tkinter

well with this code I want to make dynamic graph, I want to make my graph clear every 60 second, but I cant make it work with cla() and clf(), what is wrong?
is there any otherway to clear graph except using cla() and clf()?

```
#import lib client paho mqtt
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import redis, time
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import get_current_fig_manager

mqttc = mqtt.Client("serverclient",clean_session=False)#inisialisasi mqtt client
r = redis.Redis("localhost",6379)
start = time.time()
date = datetime.now().strftime('%S')
f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
b = f.add_subplot(111)
style.use('ggplot')
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
suhu=30
cahaya=50


def mqttx():
    #fungsi callback
    def on_message(mqttc,obj,msg):
        global LED1
        global LED2
        datasuhu = r.lrange("suhu",-1,-1)
        datacahaya = r.lrange("cahaya",-1,-1)
        print "Telah Diterima message : "+msg.payload+" topik "+msg.topic
        r.rpush(msg.topic,msg.payload)

    mqttc.on_message =  on_message

    mqttc.connect("localhost",1883)

    mqttc.subscribe("suhu")
    mqttc.subscribe("cahaya")

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

        self.graph()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Subcriber")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.xList1 = []
        self.yList1 = []
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)

        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True)
        thismanager = get_current_fig_manager()
        thismanager.window.wm_geometry("+500+0")


    def graph(self):
        suhu1 = r.lrange("suhu",-1,-1)
        cahaya1 = r.lrange("cahaya",-1,-1)
        date = datetime.now().strftime('%S')
        join1=str(''.join(suhu1))
        suhugraph=float(join1)

        join2=str(''.join(cahaya1))
        cahayagraph=float(join2)

        self.xList1.append(date)
        self.yList1.append(suhugraph)
        a.clear()
        a.axis([0, 100, 0, 60])
        a.plot(self.xList1, self.yList1,"r-")

        if date=="00" :
            plt.clf()
            plt.cla()
        else:

            self.canvas.draw()

        self.after(1000, self.graph)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1500x1400+300+300")
    app = Example(root)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    mqttx()
    mqttc.loop_start()
    main()
```

Comment: BTW: you don't have to convert seconds into string - `datetime.now().second`

Comment: `''.join()` creates string so you don't need `str()` - `suhugraph = float(''.join(suhu1))`

Comment: @furas oh yeah thanks mate, but can you help me with my problem? cant clear matplotlib figure/canvas here

Comment: @furas and I had another problem everytime I resize or minimize tkinter windows, the program become not responding

Comment: to clear graph you have to remove data from `self.xList1` and `self.xList1` -  `if date == "00": self.xList1 = []  self.yList1 = []`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear graph you have to remove data from `self.xList1` and `self.yList1`

```
self.xList1 = []
self.yList1 = []
```

because after clearing plot (`a.clear()`/`plt.clf()`/`plt.cla()`) you still have data in lists and you draw them again.

I can't run your code with `Redis` and `mqtt` so I made version with `random`

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import Tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime

import random

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Example(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # you don't need self.parent - tk.Frame sets self.master = parent        
        self.pack(expand=True, fill='both') # put frame inside Tk() window (and resize)

        self.x_list_1 = []
        self.y_list_1 = []

        self.initUI()

        self.draw()

    def initUI(self):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        self.a = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.a.axis((0, 100, 0, 60))

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    def draw(self):

        date = datetime.now().strftime('%S')
        suhugraph = random.randint(1, 60)

        if date == "00":
            self.a.clear()
            self.a.axis((0, 100, 0, 60))
            self.x_list_1 = []
            self.y_list_1 = []

        self.x_list_1.append(date)
        self.y_list_1.append(suhugraph)

        self.a.plot(self.x_list_1, self.y_list_1, "r-")
        self.canvas.draw()

        self.after(1000, self.draw)

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

BTW: [matplotlib: clearing a plot, when to use cla(), clf() or close()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228808/1832058)

---

As for responding after resizing - problem can be two loops in code: `root.mainloop()` and probably `mqttc.loop_start()`. I can't run code with `mqttc` so I can't test it.

---

BTW: updating plot without `plot()` and `clear()`

First you create empty line

```
self.line, = self.a.plot([], [], "r-")
```

and later you replace all data in line

```
self.line.set_xdata( self.x_list_1 )
self.line.set_ydata( self.y_list_1 )
```

so you don't need `clear()` and set axis again.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import Tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime

import random

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Example(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # you don't need self.parent - tk.Frame sets self.master = parent        
        self.pack(expand=True, fill='both') # put frame inside Tk() window (and resize)

        self.x_list_1 = []
        self.y_list_1 = []

        self.initUI()

        self.draw()

    def initUI(self):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        self.a = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.a.axis((0, 100, 0, 60))

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        # create empty line 
        self.line, = self.a.plot([], [], "r-")

    def draw(self):

        date = datetime.now().strftime('%S')
        suhugraph = random.randint(1, 60)

        if date == "00":
            self.x_list_1 = []
            self.y_list_1 = []

        self.x_list_1.append(date)
        self.y_list_1.append(suhugraph)

        # update data in line without `plot()` (and without `clear()`)
        self.line.set_xdata( self.x_list_1 )
        self.line.set_ydata( self.y_list_1 )

        self.canvas.draw()

        self.after(1000, self.draw)

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```