# update plot by a button click on tkinter python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am using tkinter in python. I would like to be able to plot data as I click on the button compute. and also I would like also to take into account the values given in the entries.
Up to now my script run normally, but nothing happen when I click compute of change the entry values.
here is the code :

```
#------- start
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self, win):
        x0, xt0, y0 = 10, 100, 50
        #---- First label and entry -------
        self.lbl0 = Label(win, text='Initial instant')
        self.lbl0.config(font=('Arial', 9))
        self.lbl0.place(x=x0, y=y0)
        self.t0 = Entry()
        self.t0.place(x=xt0, y=y0)
        self.t0.insert(END, str(0))
        self.t_0 = float(self.t0.get())

        #---- Second label and entry -------
        self.lbl1 = Label(win, text='Final instant')
        self.lbl1.config(font=('Arial', 10))
        self.lbl1.place(x=x0, y=y0 + 40)
        self.t1 = Entry()
        self.t1.place(x=xt0, y=y0 + 40)
        self.t1.insert(END, str(1))
        self.t_1 = float(self.t1.get())

        #---- Compute button -------
        self.btn = Button(win, text='Compute')
        self.btn.bind('<Button-1>', self.plot)
        self.btn.place(x=xt0, y=y0 + 80)

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(4.5, 3), dpi=100)

        #---- subplot 1 -------
        self.subplot1 = self.figure.add_subplot(211)
        self.subplot1.set_xlim(self.t_0, self.t_1)

        #---- subplot 2 -------
        self.subplot2 = self.figure.add_subplot(212)
        self.subplot2.set_xlabel('$Time(s)$', fontsize=11)
        self.subplot2.set_xlim(self.t_0, self.t_1)

        #---- Show the plot-------
        self.plots = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, win)
        self.plots.get_tk_widget().pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=0)

    def data(self):
        self.t_0 = float(self.t0.get())
        self.t_1 = float(self.t1.get())
        t = np.linspace(self.t_0, self.t_1, 100)
        func1 = t**0.5
        func2 = t**2.
        return t, func1, func2

    def plot(self, event):
        t, func1, func2 = self.data()
        self.t_0 = float(self.t0.get())
        self.t_1 = float(self.t1.get())
        self.subplot1.set_xlim(self.t_0, self.t_1)
        self.subplot1.plot(t, func1, 'r', lw=2.5)
        self.subplot2.set_xlim(self.t_0, self.t_1)
        self.subplot2.plot(t, func2, 'b', lw=2.5)


window = Tk()
mywin = MyWindow(window)
window.title('My model')
window.geometry("800x600+10+10")
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You were missing a small detail in your `MyWindow.plot()` method, and it is to actually **draw** your plots. If you modify it like this (note the additional line in the function):

```
def plot(self, event):
    t, func1, func2 = self.data()
    self.t_0 = float(self.t0.get())
    self.t_1 = float(self.t1.get())
    self.subplot1.set_xlim(self.t_0, self.t_1)
    self.subplot1.plot(t, func1, 'r', lw=2.5)
    self.subplot2.set_xlim(self.t_0, self.t_1)
    self.subplot2.plot(t, func2, 'b', lw=2.5)
    self.plots.draw()
```

Then you get the expected behavior (for the default case in this example):

[image]

Comment: Thank you that works pretty find ^^ ! How can I clear the plots before adding a new one ?

Comment: @user3733333 no problem. You can get more information about clearing the plots in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297595/how-to-clear-graph-tkinter). A quick and dirty way of doing it might be to use `draw` again with empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

In order to clear the plots before adding a new one, you can use :

`your_fig.clf()` (clears the figure)

or

`your_fig.cla()` (clears the axis).

or

```
ax.clear()
```

:)