# Clearing a subplot in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I have a number of subplots in a figure `fig1`, created via

```
ax = fig1.add_subplot(221)
```

I then plot stuff in each of the subplots via

```
im=ax.plot(x,y)
```

and add some axis labels via

```
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
```

I would then like to clear a specific subplot completely, as described in [When to use cla(), clf() or close() for clearing a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib). However the problem is that `ax.cla()`and `ax.clear()` seem to only clear the data from the plot, without removing the axes, axis tick labels etc. On the other hand `plt.clf()` clears the entire figure. Is there something in between? A clf-like command that clears everything in a subplot, including axis labels? Or have I simply used the commands in a wrong way?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

- `ax.clear()` clears the axes. That is, it removes all settings and data from the axes such that you are left with an axes, just as it had been just created.
- `ax.axis("off")` turns the axes off, such that all axes spines and ticklabels are hidden.
- `ax.set_visible(False)` turns the complete axes invisible, including the data that is in it.
- `ax.remove()` removes the axes from the figure.

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,3)
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.plot([2,3,1])

axes[0,1].clear()
axes[1,0].axis("off")
axes[1,1].set_visible(False)
axes[0,2].remove()

plt.show()
```

[image]