# How to plot data from two different data sets

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have trawled through some forums trying to solve this but I am new to programming and I just can't seem to figure it out.

I have two data sets with just 2 columns `(x,u)` in `data_a*.dat` and `(x,v)` in `data_b*.dat`. There are 200 files ranging from `data_a_001.dat` to `data_a_200.dat` and `data_b_001.da`t to `data_b_200.dat`

I am trying to create a set of plots
`plot_001.png` to `plot_200.png` 
such that `plot_001` has `x,u` from `data_a_001.da`t as well as `v` from `data_b_001.dat` and so on till `plot_200.png`

Thus far I've been using the following code to plot data from single files, but don't know how to get both data files on the same plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import glob

data = sorted(glob.glob('data_*'))
i=0
for d in data:
    if(i<201):
        data = np.genfromtxt(fname=d)
        x = data[:,0]
        v = data[:,1]
        plt.plot(x,v,color='blue')
        plt.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
        k = str(i)
        plt.savefig('plot'+k.zfill(4)+'.png')
        plt.close()
        i = i + 1
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

I don't mind modifying the code or just trying something new to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will be very helpful if you provide some sample of your data, your resulting plot and what plots you're trying to get.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question properly, but generally if you just do `plt.plot(x1,y1); plt.plot(x2,y2); plt.show()`, then both data sets appear in the resulting plot.

Answer (score 0):

To create a second line that overlays the first line on the same plot, use `plot.plot(x,y)` again with `x` and `y` as your new data. Matplotlib will append it to the figure and handle the rest.

Below is an example on how to create N images with each containing a plot of your data from `a.dat` and `b.dat`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import glob

files_a = sorted(glob.glob('data_a*'))
files_b = sorted(glob.glob('data_b*'))

for i, d in enumerate(files_a):
    # get file and plot from data_a_i.png
    data_a = np.genfromtxt(fname=d)
    x = data_a[:,0]
    u = data_a[:,1]
    plt.plot(x,u,color='blue')

    # get file and plot from data_b_i.png
    data_b = np.genfromtxt(fname=files_b[i])
    x = data_b[:,0]
    v = data_b[:,1]
    plt.plot(x,v,color='red')

    # format plot and save
    plt.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
    k = str(i)
    plt.savefig('plot'+k.zfill(4)+'.png')

    # clear figure, can be re-used for other plots
    plt.clf()
```

Some things to note:

- For your case, consider using `enumerate` rather than just an `item in for` loop. Enumerate (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)) gives a tuple containing the current count and value obtained from iterating over a sequence (in your case, a list).
- My current approach is not the fastest since it does `glob.glob` twice (for both files A and B). If you know the exact file names or number of files, you can definitely make it faster by opening the exact file names with just case-matching.
- I used `plt.clf()` to clear the figure created so it can be re-used again. You can take a look at this [stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib) for what it does.
- I removed `plot.show()` since the assumption is that you just want to save the `.png` files.
- If you don't clear the plot or use a function that in the back-end clears the plot, you will continue to append lines to the same figure, resulting in 400 lines (200 a and 200 b) by the end of your plot.