# Python: How to first print scatter plot and then delete it

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question regarding creating a chart in Python using matplotlib and then deleting it to create a fresh chart. I find that when I create a chart called 'firstscatter' and then put in a print statement to print it to my Python console in Spyder, it prints the chart which is fine. However I want the chart to be deleted after it has been printed so that I can have a fresh 'secondscatter' chart printed.

So all in all what I want to see is the firstscatter chart printed, then deleted, and then the secondscatter chart printed.

How do I amend my code below to see both charts printed after running the code?

Thanks a lot and really appreciate your help.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = random.rand(30)
print (x)
y = random.rand(30)
print (y)
z = random.rand(50)
print (z)

firstscatter = plt.scatter(x,y,s = z * 777)
print (firstscatter)

firstscatter.remove()
secondscatter = plt.scatter(x,y,s = z*777, c='Chartreuse')
print (secondscatter)
```

Comment: use `plt.show()` and if you want to clear the window instead of opening a second frame, use `plt.clf()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib this might be helpful

Comment: Thank you @Rocky Li . That has solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you @user7374610 . That has solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Matplotlib, you must use `plt.show()` to show the current figure. In your case:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = random.rand(30)
print (x)
y = random.rand(30)
print (y)
z = random.rand(50)
print (z)

plt.scatter(x,y,s = z * 777)
plt.show()

plt.scatter(x,y,s = z*777, c='Chartreuse')
plt.show()
```

Instead of `plt.show()`, you can use `plt.clf()` to clear the current figure.

Comment: Thank you @actuallyaswin . That has solved my problem.