# Matplotlib - Why does the figure get saved twice?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm trying to plot and save a figure using `Matplotlib` as follows:

```
plt.plot(number_of_epochs, accuracy, 'r', label='Training accuracy')
plt.plot(number_of_epochs, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation accuracy')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('accuracy.png')

plt.plot(number_of_epochs, loss, 'r', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(number_of_epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('loss.png')
```

The first figure `accuracy.png` gets saved fine. However, for `loss.png`, it contains *both* the accuracy figure and the loss figure. How can I keep only the `loss.png` figure in the latter case?

Thanks.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib

Comment: @PawełKordowski Thanks so much. Using "plt.close()" before the second plot did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `plt.figure()` inbetween the two plots. It helps you to plot in new figure, instead of plotting on the previous figure. If you don't want first figure, use `plt.close()`.

Try this

```
plt.plot(number_of_epochs, accuracy, 'r', label='Training accuracy')
plt.plot(number_of_epochs, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation accuracy')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('accuracy.png')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(number_of_epochs, loss, 'r', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(number_of_epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('loss.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `plt.close()` before the second plot would do the job.