# How do I show an animated plot?

Tags: c++, c++11, matplotlib, plot

I am using matplotlib.h to draw graphs with C++,

```
vector<double> Cx;
vector<double> Cy;
plt::plot(Cx,Cy,"*");
plt::show();
```

The problem is that I want to display the evolution of the two vectors with an animation like, so the function is here:

```
plt::show();
```

Is blocking the main thread and until the window is closed everything is blocked.

So is there anyway to change the plotted data without closing the Window and display to the user an animation

Comment: There is [an animation example](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/blob/master/examples/animation.cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only used matplotlib in python but from what you have there it seems similar. 
[When to use cla(), clf() or close() for clearing a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib) <- using plt::clf() from here may be a good start. Then once the figure is cleared maybe have a time delay and replot.

```py
plt.ion() # needed to say you want to reuse the same window
def display(some_list):
    plt.clf()
    plt.scatter(range(len(some_list)),some_list)
    plt.draw()
```

Somthing like this is used in python as an example *note* `plt.draw()` is being used to redraw on the same window rather than `show()`.

Comment: The problem is that i have to choose Blocking display or no blocking display , If I choose blocking display i can't do anything after that , and if i chose not blocking the main thread will exit and not showing anything

Comment: That worked I just added plt::pause(delay) to prevent window closing

Comment: Again I am not sure if it is the same in C++ but another method is using FuncAnimation https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html . This calls an update function repetedly to create an animation and can be used to make gifs etc.