# .plot() keeps old graph and draws new graph on top of it each time

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
def plot_and_store(df,method_name):
    '''
    Plots the given time indexed data frame and stores the plots in the folder
    '''
    for i in range(1,8):
        column_name = "T"+str(i) + "_FWD"
        series = df[column_name]
        plot = series.plot()
        figure_for_saving = plot.get_figure()
        figure_for_saving.savefig(root+"stat_plots/"+column_name+method_name)
        plot.
    return
```

I am using pandas to plot the columns in the series. However on each iteration, I get the plot of the previous column plus the new one. I am wondering how to clear the plot each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From another question:

```
    cla()   # Clear axis
    clf()   # Clear figure
    close() # Close a figure window
```

[When to use cla(), clf() or close() for clearing a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Added the sauce