# getting memory error while plotting multiple plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, out-of-memory

```
plt.clf()
plt.figure().clear()
plt.close()
plt.close(fig)
plt.close('all')
```

None of these lines which are solutions that I find in stack overflow like this one [When to use cla(), clf() or close() for clearing a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib) work for me and I constantly get `MemoryError:` or `tkinter.TclError: not enough free memory for image buffer`
I used them at the end of my loop which plotted figures.

```
for i in range(1000):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,figsize=(12, 8), dpi=400, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    axs[0].plot([0,1],[2,3])
    axs[1].plot([0,1],[2,3])
    plt.savefig("a.png")
    plt.clf()
    plt.figure().clear()
    plt.close()
    plt.close(fig)
    plt.close('all')
```

What else can I do?
And can you tell me is it a bug so it's gonna be debugged later which it doesn't seem to. so how my problem can be described (you may think why I'm asking you??!), cause there are really none possibilities that I had written those lines wrong or put it wrong where.

Comment: who closed this, this problem is totally unsolved, if it is so, please give me solution cause all answers didn't work at all!!!!

Comment: @BigBen Im familiar with that but it's not a specific problem its a general one.

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib
it's same as mine and it's enough but the only difference is  solutions worked for him

Comment: there not much possibilities for this kind of problem so if you search here my question, you'd find all questions are minimal at this level

Comment: just search my question with words memory error and matplotlib and plotting just that
and these lines I just mentioned are just functions which do all work by themselves

Comment: ok I change it but problem is the same

Comment: @BigBen did you search my question? 
man this problem is either a bug or comes out of my faults so let people come and say "why didn't  mention ... parameter" to me, you just don't close it.
I really would need it in near future.

Comment: I have no problem if someone tells me I should give more detail but because it's a mess of functions and don't give real useful information I prefer to keep it to minimal useful.

Comment: this problem may not be same for everyone also because of versions of python packages

Comment: never mind.....

Comment: if Im doing(asking question wrong) please tell me what I should add?!!?

Comment: thank you to anyone who reopened the question,
now I'm listening to any further information may needed it and I have missed it.