# Creating pyplot graphs in a for loop that close before the next is shown (with an interactive function in between)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, click

I am trying to manually curate a dataset by going through each set and choosing whether or not to keep it or reject it. To do this, I want to plot a dataset, use the click module (https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/)  to choose whether to keep it, then plot the next dataset and repeat. Currently, I am able to plot each set and choose whether or not to save it, but the problem is each graph remains above the next one. I need to go through thousands of datasets so it isn't viable to have them all plotted simultaneously.

```
for q in np.arange(0,len(x)):

    Thing = Data[x[q]-100:x[q]+400]
  
    Thing2 = Data2[x[q]-100:x[q]+400]
        
    plt.plot(Thing)
    plt.plot(Thing2)
    plt.show()

    if click.confirm('Do you want to save?', default=True):
            List.append(x[q])
```

I have seen other people recommending pyplot.ion or the matplotlib animations, but neither of them seem to be working, perhaps due to the interaction with the "Click" input box appearing. All I want to do is close each plot before the next one is made, but it is proving impossible!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the Object Orientated approach of `matplotlib`. Then you can clear the graph and draw a new one over it. For information about the OOP, see [this](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) or [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html) tutorial. And for clearing a figure check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib) post or [here](https://www.pythonpool.com/clear-plot-matplotlib/).

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't resolved the issue, even with OOP - it is still plotting the graph, opening the input box, then just creating a new graph beneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would have to clear the current figure and draw a new figure on the cleared canvas. There are multiple approaches that would work, which are pretty well described in

- [How to update a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib)

Since you are showing two graphs, I am first providing a solution that works on a single graph. Then, I am going to show a solution that works with multiple rows or columns.

---

### Solution

#### Single

The following solution and test code was used to update a single graph, and combine the data that you want to save.

```
import click
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def single(data, n_splits):
    """ Split up a dataset in n splits, and then combine the parts that you want to save.  """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    results = []

    for thing in np.hsplit(data, n_splits):
        ax.cla()
        ax.plot(thing)
        fig.show()
        plt.pause(0.0001)

        if click.confirm('Do you want to save?', default=True):
            results.append(thing)

    plt.close(fig=fig)
    return np.hstack(results) if results else []
```

Example code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Single data example
    data = np.random.randn(1000) * 10
    result = single(data, n_splits=2)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(result)
    fig.show()
    plt.pause(5)
```

#### Double

The following code is used to show two different plots at the same time, using subplots. Alternatively you can generate two figures and separately plot the different graphs.

```
def double(data, n_splits):
    """ Split up a dataset in n splits, and then combine the parts that you want to save.  """
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, squeeze=True)
    results = []

    for thing_1, thing_2 in np.hsplit(data, n_splits):

        for ax, thing in zip(axs, [thing_1, thing_2]):
            ax.cla()
            ax.plot(thing)

        fig.show()
        plt.pause(0.0001)

        if click.confirm('Do you want to save?', default=True):
            results.append([thing_1, thing_2])

    plt.close(fig=fig)
    return np.hstack(results) if results else []
```

Example code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Multiple plots example
    data = np.random.randn(2, 1000) * 10
    results = double(data, n_splits=2)

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, squeeze=True)
    for result, ax in zip(results, axs):
        ax.plot(result)

    fig.show()
    plt.pause(5)
```