# Undo plt.gcf().subplots_adjust when plotting and saving more than one chart

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

When plotting successive charts in a single Python script, `plt.clf()` does not reverse the effect of `plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)`.  The first chart is adjusted to allow x-axis labels more display space, but this change persists into the second chart.  How can one plot the second chart in `dist()` to look normal?  Even calling `sns.set()` or re-importing `plt` in the function `dist()` or after `box_adj()` is called didn't seem to fix the issue.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def box_adj():
    tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
    ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
                 data=tips, palette="Set3")
    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)
    plt.savefig('box.png')
    plt.clf()

def dist():
    ax = sns.distplot(np.random.randn(1000), kde=False)
    plt.savefig('dist.png')
    plt.clf()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    box_adj()
    dist()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.clf()` only clears the contents of the plot figure, leaving the figure intact. Its whitespace settings and its size don't change.

You could replace `plt.clf()` with `plt.close()` to fully close the figure (matplotlib will automatically create a new one when needed). Alternatively, you can explicitly call `fig = plt.figure(...)` or `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)` to create a new figure with default settings.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I guess it's my fault for not using the `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)` convention.  Here's a related post with more detail:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213522/when-to-use-cla-clf-or-close-for-clearing-a-plot-in-matplotlib